# Error TS5056: Cannot write file because it would be would be overwritten

Tags: typescript, compiler-errors, blockchain

**Problem:** I can't start blockchain on local due to this error - which popped out of the blue. I am afraid I will not be able to share much of the code for project reasons.

**Background:** Nothing special had been changed when the error appeared yesterday morning. I just tried starting my local blockchain when I got to work and that made this error appear:

```
error TS5056: Cannot write file '/dist/src/datasources/db.datasource.d.ts' because it would be overwritten by multiple input files.
```

I already looked on previously opened issues advising to set allowJs to false in tsconfig.json, as well as excluding some suggested paths, but nothing solved this for me. Tearing down all containers was useless too.

**Results:**
Expected result is simply starting the local blockchain when executing a specific script, which is currently not happening.

Comment: Please add more details about which blockchain you are using

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to solve the problem:

- In the `tsconfig.json` file:

  ```
   compilerOptions.declaration = false
  ```
- Change the name of files in the directory.
  For example, if you have the files `a.ts` and `a.json`, the compiler will try to make (if `declaration` is set to `true` in `tsconfig.json`)
  `a.d.ts` for the `a.ts` file
  and
  `a.d.ts` for the `a.json` file.

So there we have the problem.  Just change the name of `a.json` (to `ajson.json` for example), and the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the very same error.

In my case, I upgraded my lb4 version by `npm i -g @loopback/cli`, regenerate the project, and the issue goes away.

By observation, the lb4 dependencies changed by seeing from `lb4 -v`.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding the build folder to `tsconfig.json` exclude.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist" // <-- this resolves the issue
  ]
}
```